# jmpress stop step into next slide on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jmpress

I've a site using jmpress.js, while scrolling on page it automatically moved to next slide.

I want to stop stepped into next slide instead it should scroll down the page.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826838/jmpress-does-not-animate-in-chrome-44/
and my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead.

It does exactly what you want and it is designed to work in that way. It will also provide support of old browsers and mobile devices [which jmpress.js doesn't](https://github.com/jmpressjs/jmpress.js#browser-support).