# jmpress does not animate in Chrome 44

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, compatibility

Here's a link to jmpress: [jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js](http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js)

Notice how the animations do not work in Chrome 44 (latest version of Chrome as of this post).

I tried running this same page in Safari 8.0.7, and the animations worked just fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Animation works for me & I am using chrome 44 on linux ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA When you press space or use the arrow keys on the page, does the page transition from one "slide" to the other?

Comment: yes it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

this question gets old but is still relevant.

The issue is still open on github ([issue #179](https://github.com/jmpressjs/jmpress.js/issues/179))
but there is a fix in comments ([here](https://github.com/jmpressjs/jmpress.js/issues/179#issuecomment-136006901)), that works fine for me at least :)

In the jmpress.js file, in the mapProperty function,
change the line

```
    return "-" + prefix + "-" + postfix;
```

to the following:

```
    return (prefix!=="")?"-" + prefix + "-" + postfix:postfix;
```

(answer edited following @worldofjr's suggestion)